# Removing System Content Types

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, governance

I have deployed a Content Type Hub which has my organization's "Primitive" Content Types. These types are obviously inherited from the System Content Types (Document, Item, Announcement, etc..). Now, I want users to only use the Content Types from the Hub, not the System ones that are already in the Site Collections. How can I restrict users from selecting the System Types and only use the Content Types that are consumed by the Site Collections? For Example: I have a "Org Document" Content Type which has data more specific to my Organization. I want users to only see "Org Document" when adding Content Types to a list or library and not its Parent (Document) Content Type.

I see I can change the Content Type group to _Hidden but I don't think this is the best practice.

I could be on the wrong track aswell; any help would be great!